How to hide name of column from filter in Superset?
I got this filter in Superset.


How to hide column name and keep name of filter?
I think there's need to write code to CCS from this filter.

To make it I find name of element with column name by inspect ib browser.
In my case class is .css-6bztgs.
CSS-code to hide element:
.css-6bztgs {
  display: none;
}

